# apache2 points non-www to root instead of website folder

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have few different vhost created and every one has its own folder in /var/www/ like this

```
/var/www/example1/
/var/www/example2/
```

Now, when I type url with www `www.example1.com` it points to the `/var/www/example1/index.html` so that's working fine, but when I type without www `example1.com` it points to `/var/www/` and I can see all the folders, I don't have index.html in `/var/www/`.

I looked [here](http://www.awebguy.com/2011/02/seo-tip-www-or-no-www/) and created .htaccess in /var/www/:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond % ^example1.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it's not working.

This is how the all vhosts look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName *example1*
        ServerAlias *.*example1*
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/example1/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
```

I have cleared browser cache.
Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) directive doesn't take wildcards, that's what [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) is for. From the manual

> ServerName [scheme://]fully-qualified-domain-name[:port]

so you should do something like

```
ServerName example1.com
ServerAlias *.*example1*.com
```

Comment: This worked, tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can place following code Apache’s httpd.conf vhost section or in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: still not working,the ServerName in vhost was the problem.